# How to Concatenate PDFs via Pikepdf and Python without Unnecessary Disk Read-Write?

Tags: python, pdf, qpdf, pikepdf

**Current technology stack**

- img2pdf==0.4.4
- pikepdf==7.1.2
- Python 3.10
- Ubuntu 22.04

**The requirement**

A pdf file (let's call it `static.pdf`) exists in the disk. Another pdf (let's call it `dynamic.pdf`) is being generated dynamically in *memory* with img2pdf library, depending on some user input parameters.

The task is to concatenate these two pdfs as a single one (`static.pdf`, then `dynamic.pdf`) and send it as an email attachment via the SMTP library.

**Current Solution I am Employing**

This is based on the [pikepdf documentation](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/pages.html#merge-concatenate-pdf-from-several-pdfs).

- Dump `dynamic.pdf` in the disk
- Read `static.pdf` from disk with pikepdf
- Read `dynamic.pdf` from disk with pikepdf
- Concatenate them with list-like API provided by pikepdf, let's call this `final.pdf`.
- Dump `final.pdf` on disk with pikepdf api
- Read it from disk with `open(file='final.pdf', mode='rb')` as bytes
- Attach the bytes to the email message

**What I want**

Remove all the unnecessary disk-I/O when I already have `dynamic.pdf` in memory, and the final result is needed to be attached to email as bytes (no need to persist on disk). So ideally, the only disk operation should be reading `static.pdf`.

But I cannot find much information on the pikepdf site about in-memory concatenation. Moreover, I am also not certain whether a `pikepdf.Pdf` object can expose the *exact same bytes* as what I would get if I dump the pdf on disk and then read it using python native `open` function.

So any ideas around this would be helpful, even if there are other libraries that allow this functionality. The constraints on other libraries would be

- Plays will with my tech stack (python, Ubuntu and also needs to run on windows)
- FOSS, and trustworthy enough

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `pikepdf.Pdf`](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/main.html#pikepdf.Pdf), the `Pdf.open` and `Pdf.save` methods accept a file-like object instead of a filename, so you can use `io.BytesIO` here.

For example,

```py
import io
import img2pdf
from pikepdf import Pdf

def pdf_from_bytes(data):
    return Pdf.open(io.BytesIO(data))

def add_png_to_end(static_pdf_path, png_file_path):
    # Adds a PNG to the end of an existing PDF document and returns the bytes.
    static_pdf = Pdf.open(static_pdf_path)
    png_pdf = pdf_from_bytes(img2pdf.convert(png_file_path))
    new_pdf = Pdf.new()
    new_pdf.pages.extend(static_pdf.pages)
    new_pdf.pages.extend(png_pdf.pages)
    res = io.BytesIO()
    new_pdf.save(res)
    return res.getvalue()
```